# Python: Using Pandas library. How to keep quotes on text?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm using the following code of Python using the Pandas library. The purpose of the code is to join 2 CSV files and works as exptected. In the CSV files all the values are within "". When using the Pandas libray they dissapear. I wonder what I can do to keep them? I have read the documentation and tried lots of options but can't seem to get it right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
import pandas

csv1 = pandas.read_csv('WS-Produktlista-2015-01-25.csv', quotechar='"',comment='"')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('WS-Prislista-2015-01-25.csv', quotechar='"', comment='"')
merged = csv1.merge(csv2, on='id')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Instead of getting a line like this:

```
"1","Cologne","4711","4711","100ml",
```

I'm getting:

```
1,Cologne,4711,4711,100ml,
```

**EDIT:**

I now found the problem. My files contains a header with 16 columns. The data lines contains 16 values separated with ",".

Just found that some lines contains values within "" that contains ",". This is confusing the parser. Instead of expecting 15 commas, it finds 18. One example below:

```
"23210","Cosmetic","Lancome","Eyes Virtuose Palette Makeup",**"7,2g"**,"W","Decorative range","5x**1,2**g Eye Shadow + **1,2**g Powder","http://image.jpg","","3660732000104","","No","","1","1"
```

How can make the parser ignore the comma sign within ""?

Comment: So is the text in the df containing quotes or is it that when writing to csv it's missing quotes? If the former try `pandas.read_csv('WS-Produktlista-2015-01-25.csv', quotechar='"',comment='"', quoting=3)` if the latter try `merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=Falsem quoting=3)`

Comment: The original text already contains qoutes and I want to keep them as they are. But they dissapear during the pandas operation. When trying your suggestion of merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, quoting=3) I'm getting the following error:

Comment: I will ask again, at which point are the quotes lost? When loading or writing to csv

Comment: File "lib.pyx", line 899, in pandas.lib.write_csv_rows (pandas\lib.c:15697)
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

Comment: The truth is I can't really tell, I'm guessing when writing

Comment: Please try `pandas.read_csv('WS-Produktlista-2015-01-25.csv', quoting=3)` and `merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, quoting=3)`